# How can I achieve this print look for a Bookcover?

Tags: print-design, print-production, book

i'm currently designing a book cover and try to find a possibility to produce a golden square like in the picture, with text on it. I think in the picture they used a sticker. How can I achieve this Print effect, with a hot foil stamping in gold and the text basic in black without finishing?

[image: I found this picture on the Internet. Not sure how they produced it]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I don't think that's an example of hot foil work, it's also not gold.  Possibly spot UV varnish?

Comment: @BillyKerr thank you for your answer. I have already looked into UV Varnish. So far I have only found examples in which clear Varnish was used over normal ink. How can I get this shiny look? (It doesn´t matter at this point wether its gold or silver, tough :)

Comment: UV varnish is transparent. If you do a UV varnish over a gold coloured ink, it will look shiny. It won't look metallic though. Also I don't think overprinting gold foil would work at all. Speak to your printer before you try something experimental. Might not be possible, or end up being too costly.

Comment: Although your image might not show an example of hot foil work, I think a nice result could be achieved with golden hot foil. What do you mean by "without finishing"?

Answer (score 1):

There are printable foils out there, but it requires a special ink usually.

However, if hot foil stamping is an option, you could have the printer foil stamp the gold block, then come back and use a black pigment foil to foil stamp the words.  Make sure you check with them that none of the text is too small for a die.